# How to find the row whcih contains from the pivot table

Tags: pandas

My DF is below. FInd the rows contains

```
gender  FEMALE  MALE    OTHER
AGE         
[15-20]     0   1   0
[25-30]     0   1   0
```

`df_1[df_1['AGE'].str.contains("15-20")]`

Expected Out

```
gender  FEMALE  MALE    OTHER
    AGE         
    [15-20]     0   1
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: @davidbilla added the expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use str.contains:

```
df.loc[df.index.str.contains("15-20")]
```

Or as suggested by @anky_91, the loc operation can be removed:

```
df[df.index.str.contains("15-20")]
```

Comment: Thanks @anky_91. Have updated my answer with your suggestion. Just can't remember why loc can be removed here?

Answer (score 0):

As in your sample, its index `AGE` looks like a list of string to me. It is not a simple string, so checking on straight string `"15-20"` won't work.

You may try this:

```
df_out = df[df.index.map(lambda x: x[0] == "15-20")]

###or 

df_out = df[df.index.map(lambda x: "15-20" in x)]

Out[132]:
gender   FEMALE  MALE  OTHER
AGE
[15-20]       0     1      0
```

Or using `str` accessor to get first element

```
df_out = df[df.index.str[0] ==  "15-20"]

Out[133]:
gender   FEMALE  MALE  OTHER
AGE
[15-20]       0     1      0
```